# Modify ows_MetaInfo in Sharepoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

If you view a SharePoint calendar in MS Outlook and change the color of that item in Outlook, the SharePoint ows_MetaInfo gets changed from this:

`2362;#`

to This:

`2362;#vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
FollowUp:SW|
vti_serverversion:SW|2
vti_versionhistory:SW|473e1c0c47cf034d9969c8513def1903:4
vti_clientversion:SW|4
BusyStatus:SW|2
Categories:SW|Red Category
Priority:SW|
IntendedBusyStatus:SW|
vti_externalversion:IW|3`

I have a C# program that creates the SP calendar entry but I would like to be able to modify this ows_MetaInfo Categories property so that I can color code these items so that users that view this in Outlook will see these color codes.

I have searched on everything that I can thing of. I have seen people reading this ows_MetaInfo data but nothing that says how it can be changed. As stated earlier, I'm doing this in C# and I would like to change the ows_MetInfo Categories property so that Outlook users will see color coded calendar entries.

Any help would be Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Hello, i don't think you need to modify the ows_MetaInfo field but have a look at the content type fields. IMO there is a Category field. Updating this with the right category should be enough to adjust the coloring (I think event receivers will fire which will eventually update the ows_MetaInfo for you

Comment: I agree, there is a category field, but this is not where the `Categories:SW|Red Category` is stored that outlook looks at to make this color determination. The reason that I know that is because I already set the category field to something else. When you go into outlook to look at that item it's not colored. When I change the color that category field is not overwritten but the ows_MetaInfo is updated. Is there an accessible hidden field somewhere that stores this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching around for quite some time to figure this out and I overlooked the most obvious answer... :) All I had to do was ask for help for me to finally figure it out! LOL :D

MetaInfo is just another String field. When you make a color change in Outlook to a SharePoint attached calendar item it, just adds text to that field that specifies the color along with some other default items. To change the color you can just specify it with something like `cListItem["MetaInfo"] = "Categories:SW|Red Category\r\n";` and it will just change the Categories field leaving the others alone.

For completeness, I'm going to post my entire test example. (Because I hate it when I find the answer to a problem but only part of the answer is posted leaving me to guess at what else was in the code that made the example actually work :) )

This is done is VS2013 using a Console App

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;

namespace SharePointSetMetaInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://mySharePointServer/sites/MySite/"))
            {

                context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserName", "myPassword", "MYDOMAIN");
                SP.List calendarList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Calendar");
                ListItem cListItem = calendarList.GetItemById(2301);//This is one way to retrieve an item for update. You can also use a Caml Query
                context.Load(cListItem);
                cListItem["MetaInfo"] = "Categories:SW|Red Category\r\n";
                cListItem.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who is trying to programmatically change the colors on SharePoint calendar items as they show up in Outlook. This is not applicable to how SharePoint calendar items appear in SharePoint, only Outlook.